# Image Color Change After Watermark Apply in PHP

Tags: php, css, watermark, php-gd

Developed Watermark Script,but on adding water mark the image color changes.

```
// merge the source image and the watermark
  imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));
```

Change Image color after Watermark.

[Without Watermark Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKqJE.jpg)

[After Watermark Apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGV8t.jpg)

Comment: use ``createimagetruecolor`` for your ``$watermark`` resource

Comment: I need result Image not only watermark image.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: I already done Watermark. Only need change result image color. looks like this type: http://soydecristo.hn/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `GD` functions, just apply a filter to your image:

```
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
```

Check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

Comment: Generate none. not received any result.

Comment: Yes,  do it. I can use after this funcation.                                                                                        imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));